# Importing data from notepad to python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have notepad with data in this style:

10.0.0.1 admin admin
10.0.0.2 admin admin
10.0.0.3 admin admin

I want to take this data from notepad and import it into python dictionary where key values will be
"ip":"10.0.0.1", "name":"admin","passwd":"admin"
And by loop i will put those key values to netmiko to connect each device one by one. But have no clue how to convert this data from notepad to dictionary :(

Current code:

```
desktop = "C:\\Users\\Dawid\\Desktop\\" 
with open(desktop+"devices.txt",'r') as file:
     x = file.read().split()
for i in x:     
    var = {
        'ip':i,
        'name':'admin',
        'passwd':'admin'
     }
    a = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**var)
```

Comment: is your whole notepad space separated?

Comment: Tehre is format like that:
ip <space> user <space> password <enter>
ip <space>user <space> password <enter>

Comment: have you tried anything? Because this seems like a basic file loading.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Till now i needed only ip because login and passwd were the same and it looked like this:
`desktop = "C:\\Users\\Dawid\\Desktop\\"

with open(desktop+"devices.txt",'r') as file:
    x = file.read().split()

for i in x:
    var = {
        'ip':i,
        'name':'admin',
        'passwd':'admin'
    }
a = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**var)`

But have no clue how to modify it to take aswell login and passwd and import it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about reading the file into Python and then splitting it into a list and then each list item into a dict:
Added a possibility of name and password missing from the text file line, leaving only the IP as a usable variable.

```
dir = r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\"

with open(fr"{dir}file.txt", "r") as f:
    a = f.read().splitlines()

a_list = [item.split(" ") for item in a]

for network in a_list:
    if len(network) != 3:
        network_dict = {"ip": network[0], "name": "default_name", "passwd": "default_password"}
    else:
        network_dict = {"ip": network[0], "name": network[1], "passwd": network[2]}
    #do whatever is needed with the dict here
```

If you want to have a directory as a variable, use `raw string` as such

```
dir = r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\"
```

This way you don't have to escape special characters including backslashes.

Comment: Works like i wanted too, tnak you very much :)

Comment: Btw is there any option to assing default value to for example name and passwd keys if the value is not in notepad then will use default?

Comment: @typovy If it's always both the name and password that could be missing, then just check if there is only 1 element in `network` (inside `for network in a_list:)`. If it could be either name or password, then it gets a little more complicated as you can't know which one is missing.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to figure it out somehow

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is really one line separated as given, and what you really want is a list of dicts, here is one option.

```
np = "10.0.0.1 admin admin 10.0.0.2 admin admin 10.0.0.3 admin admin"
tokens = np.split()

dicts = []
while tokens:
    dicts.append({"pass": tokens.pop(), "user": tokens.pop(), "ip": tokens.pop()})

[print(d) for d in dicts]
```

yielding:

```
➜ python np.py
{'pass': 'admin', 'user': 'admin', 'ip': '10.0.0.3'}
{'pass': 'admin', 'user': 'admin', 'ip': '10.0.0.2'}
{'pass': 'admin', 'user': 'admin', 'ip': '10.0.0.1'}
```

Comment: OP just said that there is a new line after each block (ip, name, password)

Comment: `split` should handle that just fine, actually. I just checked and it works fine it seems.